# jQuery variables and $.post

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with some code. I'm using `console.log()` to output the variables contents but it seems like `$.post()` is taking to long thus my variable isn't being set properly. Here is my code.

```
$.tmsmm = { 
    duplicate_meeting : "something"
}; 
$.post("scripts/check_duplicate_meetings.php", { meeting_date: meeting_date, meeting_type: meeting_type }, function(data) {
    $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting = data;
    console.log("myVar: " + $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting);
});

console.log("myVar2: " + $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting);
```

What's outputted:

> myVar2: something
>   myVar: this is ajax data!

As you can see, myVar2 is being logged before myVar. How do I get around this?

UPDATE: The reason this solutions suited my situation best vs calling a function upon success or completion using $.post is that i have a lot of code that comes after this sample that is dependent upon the variables value. I only logged the value 2 different times to troubleshoot why my variable wasnt set outside of the $.post function. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the ajax call to be synchronous by using $.ajax and using the `async` property. However, this can cause the browser to hang and should be avoided.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

However, that defeats the purpose of using ajax in the first place. Your example doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Why exactly do you need to check `duplicate_meeting` before you get a return?

Comment: +1 - Just what I was going to write. To the OP, do note that some browsers may hang or stop rendering until the now synchronous request is complete.

Comment: Why set it to `async` if you can listen for a `complete` or `success` event?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.tmsmm = { 
    duplicate_meeting : "something"
}; 
$.post("scripts/check_duplicate_meetings.php", { meeting_date: meeting_date, meeting_type: meeting_type }, function(data) {
    $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting = data;
    console.log("myVar: " + $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting);
    console.log("myVar2: " + $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting);
});
```

Put the myVar2 in the $.post callback function to display it after myVar.

Comment: +1 that's what i had in my answer too. seems like the simplest and most effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

The post request happens asynchronously. So after you issue the `post` request, execution immediately jumps to the `console.log` at the bottom. You need to handle any response in a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Put your myvar 2 code within a success function for $.post. That way you ensure its only run if $.post was successful.

You can see an example here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` is asynchronous. The callback will run whenever the server returns something, and not before. The `console.log` is directly after it, and will run synchronously, before the server has returned a response.

You can either move your `console.log` code into the callback, or use `$.ajax` and set the `async` option to `false`. The latter option is crazy and you should basically never do it, because the browser will freeze (completely!) until your server has responded. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var checkDuplicateMeetings = $.post("scripts/check_duplicate_meetings.php", { meeting_date: meeting_date, meeting_type: meeting_type }, function(data) {
    $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting = data;
    console.log("myVar: " + $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting);
});

checkDuplicateMeetings.complete(function(){
   console.log("myVar2: " + $.tmsmm.duplicate_meeting); 
});
```

For context, I am demonstrating it here with the `complete` event. However, you can use `success` or `error` events as you see fit. Listening for a `complete` event will ensure your code will be the last bit to run after the request has been made successfully or with errors. If you want to check and run a specific code for success or fail, listen for a `success` or `error` event accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your second call to console.log() is going to complete first every time.  The first call will happen upon successful completion of the ajax call and the execution context will happen so quickly that the second call will happen first.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing check_duplicate_meetings.php to just have

```
<?php echo 'hi'; ?>
```

for instance,

Then you can see if it is an error in your PHP file. The variable 'data' won't get loaded I think if the php file has an error occurring.

If it does have an error, try running `check_duplicate_meetings.php` and set the variables manually in the beginning of the file to test it.

Comment: This isn't a problem with the PHP - the `$.post` request is sent asynchronously, meaning that any code after it won't wait for the server to return data; it will just carry on.